# EndScene of CollapsibleToolbar always have Paddings

Tags: android, xml

I'm going to make CollapsibleToolbar. Look at the embedded gif.
https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R1280x0/?scode=mtistory2&fname=https%3A%2F%2Fk.kakaocdn.net%2Fdn%2Fb1H8Rj%2FbtqwrADyPUy%2FUV2LzlICIaQXhIPqIazATK%2Fimg.gif

At the end_scene, Toolbar has a padding although its padding is none.
What happened to them?

```
Part of content_main.xml

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <foo.bar.CollapsibleToolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/constraintToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layoutDescription="@xml/main_motion"
            android:minHeight="160dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/month"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="April"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/month_goal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/month"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="1/30"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/month"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_icon"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:contentDescription="@string/this_app_name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <com.dinuscxj.progressbar.CircleProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/days_graph"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.24000001"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:line_width="20dp"
                app:progress_end_color="@color/colorAccent"
                app:progress_shader="sweep"
                app:progress_start_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:progress_start_degree="-90"
                app:progress_stroke_cap="round"
                app:progress_stroke_width="20dp"
                app:progress_text_color="@android:color/black"
                app:style="solid_line" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/cv_profile"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_elevation"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/selector_ripple"
                android:contentDescription="Profile"
                android:src="@drawable/img_default_profile"

                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/days_graph"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/days_graph"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/days_graph"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/days_graph"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/circle_profile_overlay"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:contentDescription="Profile"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_check_circle"

                android:elevation="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/days_graph"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/days_graph"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/days_graph"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/days_graph" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/graph_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:text="30/365"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/days_graph" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/change_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/usual_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/usual_margin"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:text="@string/click_to_change_goal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"/>


        </foo.bar.CollapsibleToolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

```
main_moton_end.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="April"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month_goal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/month"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="1/30"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/month"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/this_app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <com.dinuscxj.progressbar.CircleProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/days_graph"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:line_width="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/cv_profile"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/img_default_profile"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/days_graph"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/days_graph"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/days_graph"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/days_graph"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle_profile_overlay"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:contentDescription="Profile"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check_circle"

        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/days_graph"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/days_graph"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/days_graph"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/days_graph" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/graph_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:bufferType="spannable"
        android:text="30/365"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/change_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
xml/main_motion.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Copyright (C) 2018 The Android Open Source Project
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@layout/main_motion_start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@layout/main_motion_end"
        motion:duration="1000"
        motion:onTouchUp="stop"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">

    </Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

```
CollapsibleToolbar.kt

/*
 * Copyright (C) 2018 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package foo.bar

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

class CollapsibleToolbar @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : MotionLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    override fun onOffsetChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout?, verticalOffset: Int) {
        progress = -verticalOffset / appBarLayout?.totalScrollRange?.toFloat()!!
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        (parent as? AppBarLayout)?.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: `At the end_scene, Toolbar has a padding` what do you mean?

Comment: recommend to see link (picture-gif)